# Loaded product missing media_gallery attribute

Tags: magento-1.7, product, image

I am loading a product like so:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', 'MyStockCode');
```

Then I try to get the images using:

```
$existingGallery = $product->getMediaGallery('images');
```

but it comes back with a null value. When inspecting `_data` against `$product` the `media_gallery` attribute is missing.

From all the references I have read, this is how to load the images against a product but this doesn't seem to be working for me.

Notes:

I can see the images in the admin area against that product so they are definitely there.

I am doing this in the admin area, not frontend.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you load the product by ID the media gallery will be loaded:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$id = $product->getIdBySku($sku);
$product->load($id);
```

The difference is that `loadByAttribute` loads the product via a collection.
Alternatively, if you already have a loaded product and simply want to load the associated images, you can use

```
$product->getResource()->getAttribute('media_gallery')
    ->getBackend()->afterLoad($product);
```

After that all images of the product are accessible via `$product->getMediaGalleryImages()`

Answer (score -2):

Another approach thats works too:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', 'MyStockCode'); 
$product->load('media_gallery'); //just add this line of code before you fetch gallery images
$existingGallery = $product->getMediaGalleryImages();
```

Comment: It seems to be working even if you write `$product->load();`. Is it equivalent or does it something smart like loading just the attribute if you specified a valid one? Or does it just reload the product? In which case it's probably better to just do `$p = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');$p->load($p->getIdBySku('MyStockCode'))`.